# How to write a common Get and Delete methods using generics, for data access with NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, generics

In the current application there are two sets of objects, basically used as Domain and NHibernate objects, with interfaces. Domain objects are used by the presentation and business layers, where as NHibernate objects are used by only Data Layer. Currently, for any DB transaction business layer passes the Domain objects to Data layer, which internally converts to NHibernate through auto-mapper.

**I would like to implement common Save, Get and Delete methods.**
I have used generics, repository and reflection to implement common Save method as below with interfaces.

**Does anyone have any insight on how to create a common Get and Delete methods using generics and reflection for data access with NHibernate?**

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but you can try something like this.

```
public abstract class BaseRepo<TIdType, TPersistentType>
{
    protected ISession Session { get; private set; }

    protected BaseRepo(ISession session)
    {
        Session = session;
    }

    public virtual void Save(TPersistentType request)
    {
        Session.Save(request);
    }

    public virtual TPersistentType GetById(TIdType id)
    {
        return (TPersistentType)Session.Load(typeof(TPersistentType), id);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TPersistentType> QueryList()
    {
        return Session.Linq<TPersistentType>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this is the code you're looking for :

- Author : BantenCity (http://84nt3nc1ty.blogspot.com/)
- Created Date : April, 13, 2010
- Filename : GenericDao.cs

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  using NHibernate;
  using NHibernate.Criterion;

  using Spring.Data.NHibernate.Generic.Support;

  namespace Mapits.Library.Dao
  {
  public class GenericDao<T, ID> : HibernateDaoSupport, IGenericDao<T, ID>
  {
      #region Constants
      private const string Asc = "Asc";
      private const string Desc = "Desc";
      #endregion

      #region Update
      /// <summary>
      /// Update Entity
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="entity"></param> 
      public void Update(T entity)
      {
          HibernateTemplate.Update(entity);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Update List of Entity
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="listEntity"></param>
      public void Update(List<T> listEntity)
      {
          foreach (object entity in listEntity)
          {
              HibernateTemplate.Update(entity);
          }
      }
      #endregion

      #region Save
      /// <summary>
      /// Save Entity
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="entity"></param>
      public void Save(T entity)
      {
          HibernateTemplate.Save(entity);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Save List of Entity
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="listEntity"></param>
      public void Save(List<T> listEntity)
      {
          foreach (object entity in listEntity)
          {
              HibernateTemplate.Save(entity);
          }
      }
      #endregion

      #region Delete
      /// <summary>
      /// Delete Entity
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="entity"></param>
      public void Delete(T entity)
      {
          HibernateTemplate.Delete(entity);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Delete List of Entity
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="listEntity"></param>
      public void Delete(List<T> listEntity)
      {
          foreach (object entity in listEntity)
          {
              HibernateTemplate.Delete(entity);
          }
      }
      #endregion

      #region SaveOrUpdate
      /// <summary>
      /// Save or Update  Entity
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="entity"></param>
      public void SaveOrUpdate(T entity)
      {
          HibernateTemplate.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Flush Entity from Hibernate Session
      /// </summary>
      public void Flush()
      {
          HibernateTemplate.Flush();
          //Session.Flush();
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Evict Entity from Hibernate Session
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="entity"></param>
      public void Evict(T entity)
      {
          HibernateTemplate.Evict(entity);
          //Session.Evict(entity);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Save or Update List of Entity
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="listEntity"></param>
      public void SaveOrUpdate(List<T> listEntity)
      {
          foreach (object entity in listEntity)
          {
              HibernateTemplate.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
          }
      }
      #endregion

      #region GetList
      /// <summary>
      /// GetList by CreateByQuery
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="query"></param>
      /// <param name="param"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public List<T> CreateByQuery(string query, Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> param)
      {
          IQuery q = Session.CreateQuery(query);
          SetString(q, param);
          return (List<T>)q.List<T>();
      }

      public IList GetListByCriteriaQuery(int minResult, int maxResult, ProjectionList projectionList,
          ICriterion[] criterion, Dictionary<string, string> orders)
      {
          ICriteria crit = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));

          crit.SetFirstResult(minResult);
          if (maxResult != 0) crit.SetMaxResults(maxResult);

          if (projectionList != null)
          {
              crit.SetProjection(projectionList);
          }

          if (criterion != null)
          {
              foreach (ICriterion iCrit in criterion)
              {
                  crit.Add(iCrit);
              }
          }

          if (orders != null)
          {
              foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> order in orders)
              {
                  if (order.Value == Asc)
                  {
                      crit.AddOrder(Order.Asc(order.Key));
                  }
                  if (order.Value == Desc)
                  {
                      crit.AddOrder(Order.Desc(order.Key));
                  }
              }
          }

          IList list = crit.List();

          if (list.Count > 0)
              return list;

          return null;
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// Get List By Criteria Query
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="minResult"></param>
      /// <param name="maxResult"></param>
      /// <param name="projection"></param>
      /// <param name="criterion"></param>
      /// <param name="orders"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public IList<T> GetListByCriteriaQuery(int minResult, int maxResult,
          ICriterion[] criterion, Dictionary<string, string> orders)
      {
          ICriteria crit = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));

          crit.SetFirstResult(minResult);
          if (maxResult != 0) crit.SetMaxResults(maxResult);

          if (criterion != null)
          {
              foreach (ICriterion iCrit in criterion)
              {
                  crit.Add(iCrit);
              }
          }

          if (orders != null)
          {
              foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> order in orders)
              {
                  if (order.Value == Asc)
                  {
                      crit.AddOrder(Order.Asc(order.Key));
                  }
                  if (order.Value == Desc)
                  {
                      crit.AddOrder(Order.Desc(order.Key));
                  }
              }
          }

          IList<T> list = crit.List<T>();

          if (list.Count > 0)
              return list;

          return null;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// GetList by CreateByNamedQuery - Native SQL
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="query"></param>
      /// <param name="param"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public List<T> CreateByNamedSQLQuery(string query, Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> param)
      {
          IQuery q = Session.GetNamedQuery(query);
          SetString(q, param);
          return (List<T>)q.List<T>();
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// GetList by GetByNamedQuery - Native SQL
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="query"></param>
      /// <param name="param"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public IList GetByNamedQuery(string query, Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> param)
      {
          IQuery q = Session.GetNamedQuery(query);
          SetString(q, param);
          return q.List();
      }
      #endregion

      #region Miscellaneous
      /// <summary>
      /// 
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="id"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public T Load(ID id)
      {
          return HibernateTemplate.Load<T>(id);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Check if row exist by id
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="id"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public T Get(ID id)
      {
          T t = (T)Session.Get(typeof(T), id);

          return t;
      }

      public T GetByInt(Int32 id)
      {
          T t = (T)Session.Get(typeof(T), id);
          return t;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Get Entity by Criteria
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="fieldname"></param>
      /// <param name="value"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public T GetByCriteria(string fieldname, string value)
      {
          ICriteria crit = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));
          crit.Add(Restrictions.Eq(fieldname, value));
          return (T)crit.UniqueResult();
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Get ISQLQuery by CreateByISQLQuery - Native SQL
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="query"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public ISQLQuery CreateByISQLQuery(string query)
      {
          ISQLQuery q = Session.CreateSQLQuery(query);

          return q;
      }

      #endregion

      #region Private Methods...

      private void SetString(IQuery q, Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> param)
      {
          foreach (KeyValuePair<List<string>, List<string>> valuePair in param)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < valuePair.Key.Count; i++)
              {
                  q.SetString(valuePair.Key[i], valuePair.Value[i]);
              }
          }
      }

      #endregion
  }
  ```

  }